# Open image in new window with getElementsByClassName (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

How can I open an image in a new window by using its class? (It has to be JavaScript)

```
 function swipe() {
var largeImage = document.getElementByClassName('largeImage');
largeImage.style.display = 'block';
largeImage.style.width=200+"px";
largeImage.style.height=200+"px";
var url=largeImage.getAttribute('src');
 window.open(url,'Image','width=largeImage.stylewidth,height=largeImage.style.height,
resizable=1');}
```

HTML:

```
<img class="largeImage" src="image1.jpg" onClick="swipe();"/>
```

Comment: Why ? Into `swipe()`, `this` is referring to the clicked image.

Comment: use `var largeImage = document.querySelector('.largeImage');` instead

Comment: @adeneo I tried your tip and it worked but only for one image. If I have many pictures I thought that you could use var largeImage = document.querySelectorAll('.largeImage'); but it didn't work. Any solutions?

Comment: Do you want to open many images in popup windows ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the class either. Please check this fiddle. -

http://jsfiddle.net/Lu7dn1yg/

#### HTML

```
<img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2014/perseidmeteorshower14/sprite-initial.png" onclick="swipe(this)">
```

#### JS

```
function swipe(imgelem) {
    var src = imgelem.src;
    window.open(src);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use: `document.getElementsByClassName` instead of `document.getElementById`.

This way is not supported by old browsers. Thats way i recommend you to use jquery.